# Can I check with jQuery if element has specific class and edit only this element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

```js
if (jQuery("li.store .premise")[0]) {
    jQuery(".address .arrow").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="store">
    <div class="address">
        <span class="arrow"></span>
        <div class="results-toggle">
            <div class="shop-address">
                <div class="street-block">
                    <div class="thoroughfare">demo address</div>
                    <div class="premise">additional info</div>
                </div>
                <div class="addressfield-container-inline locality-block country-BG"><span
                        class="locality">New York</span></div>
                <span class="country">USA</span>
            </div>
            <div class="shop-phone">+1 4258741</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to check if an element contains specific class and if it does, then to edit only this or these elements.

I have a list of stores and I want if some of them contain specific class to remove the arrows.

I tried with this but it removes all elements with a class arrow and I want to remove the only storeеthat have the specific class which in this case is `class="premise"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest using get parent element then find class for .arrow then remove method using removed.

```
$(".store .premise").closest(".address").find('.arrow').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a collection of `premise`s, use `.closest` to navigate to their ancestor `address`, from which you can get to the `.arrow`s:

```
$('div.store .premise').closest('.address').find('.arrow').remove();
```

(assuming that the `.store` element in your actual code is a `<li>`, otherwise use `div.store` or just `.store`)

```js
$('div.store .premise').closest('.address').find('.arrow').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="store">
  <div class="address">
    <span class="arrow">arrow here</span>
    <div class="results-toggle">
      <div class="shop-address">
        <div class="street-block">
          <div class="thoroughfare">demo address</div>
          <div class="premise">additional info</div>
        </div>
        <div class="addressfield-container-inline locality-block country-BG"><span class="locality">New York</span></div>
        <span class="country">USA</span>
      </div>
      <div class="shop-phone">+1 4258741</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```